# BigQuery access through service account fails with dataset not found in location US

Tags: google-bigquery

I changed the service key for my program and now I get the following error:

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Not found: Dataset test-123:flights was not found in location US
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:106)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getQueryResults(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:584)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$34.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1203)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$34.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1198)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getQueryResults(BigQueryImpl.java:1197)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getQueryResults(BigQueryImpl.java:1181)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job$1.call(Job.java:329)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job$1.call(Job.java:326)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.poll(RetryHelper.java:64)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.waitForQueryResults(Job.java:325)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.getQueryResults(Job.java:291)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.query(BigQueryImpl.java:1168)
```

The dataset is actually in the location EU. I looked in the query history of the project and the query which is executed and throws the error has the location US.

If I use the old key everything works as expected. The new key has the following roles:
Big Query Admin

I'm using the following library and code:
"com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.90.0"

```
val query = "$label MERGE $dataset.$tableName T " +
            "USING $tmpTableName S " +
            "ON T.$mergeColumnName = S.$mergeColumnName " +
            "WHEN MATCHED THEN ... "

    val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
            .addTableDefinition(tmpTableName,
                    ExternalTableDefinition.newBuilder(sourceFile, schema, format)
                            .setCompression("GZIP")
                            .build())
            .build();
            bigQuery.query(queryConfig)
```

Is there a way to specify the location in code or to specify a default location for the service account?

Fun fact the following code lists the dataset:

```
val datasets = bigQuery.listDatasets(DatasetListOption.pageSize(100))
    for (dataset in datasets.iterateAll()) {
        log.info("$dataset")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with:

bigQuery.query(queryConfig, JobId.newBuilder().setLocation("EU").build())